# createthread() how to release memory better?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to close a thread and release memory after `createthread()`. I did this with return `createthread()`'s callback and `closehandle()`. Some people said this can't release memory clear. I am testing it, so far, so good. It looks ok?

I take a flag:endThread to do this, there are too many flags, too many if, it looks ugly, how to make it better?

```
typedef void(*pfunc)(char*);
HANDLE H_thread=NULL;
int endThread = 0;//0:thread not start;1:end thread order;2:thread started
void mycall(char*s){
    cout << "callback" << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
}
static DWORD WINAPI myfunc(LPVOID lp)
{
    while (1)
    {
        ((pfunc)lp)("2222");
        cout << "thread..........." << endl;
        Sleep(10);
        if (1==endThread)
        {
            endThread = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
void thread_callback(pfunc call){
    if (0==endThread)
    {
        H_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, myfunc, call, 0, NULL);
        endThread = 2;
        call("1111");
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        thread_callback(mycall);
        endThread = 1;
        //wait for thread end.
        while (endThread != 0){
            Sleep(1);
        }
        CloseHandle(H_thread);
        H_thread = NULL;
    }
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What memory are you trying to release?  I don't see any memory allocations that need to be released ... although you are using the global variable `endThread` incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like you're asking for [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), isn't you?

Comment: I want get something to replace the endThread@Alisson.what's wrong with endThread@Harry Johnston

Comment: So much wrong, I wouldn't even know, where to start. Please get yourself a book on multithreading, and programming in general.

Comment: I agree with IInspectable. This code is so completely broken that nothing but a complete rewrite can achieve any goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating and destroying threads over and over. It doesn't even check if the thread was done. It's unlikely that that's your goal. Use `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` to make sure that the thread is done. In a Window program (not console) you can use `SendMessage` from the thread to GUI thread, to indicate that the thread is done.

Try the example below. Also you can use `system("pause");` instead of `while(1);`, but that's only necessary if you are running the program from VS IDE in debug mode. See also this [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

struct T_data {
    std::wstring text;
};

DWORD WINAPI thread_function(void *ptr) {
    T_data* data = (T_data*)ptr;
    MessageBoxW(GetConsoleWindow(), data->text.c_str(), 0, 0);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    T_data *data = new T_data;
    data->text = L"hello world";
    DWORD threadId;
    HANDLE handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_function, data, 0, &threadId);

    if (handle) {
        printf("thread started\n");
        while (WaitForSingleObject(handle, 100))
            printf(".");
        printf("\nthread finished\n");
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }

    delete data;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Deleting the data can get tricky if data is shared, depending on where and how you want to do that. The calling thread may delete the data before receiving thread is finished processing it. I'll leave that out since you haven't shown any such shared data in the question.

Comment: Firstly,thank you for the detailed answer. In fact,I have a flag to make sure thread was done in thread `endThread = 0;return 0;`,and only one place can do `endThread=0`,in _tmain() ,it will wait thread done `while (endThread != 0)`,then `CloseHandle(H_thread)`.why you all don't think it can work well?I can't understand.

Comment: You are using `while (endThread != 0);` this hijacks the cpu, it defeats the purpose of threads. I didn't notice that before. It makes it worse. Run the task manager and watch the CPU/resources usage of your console program to see what is happening.

Comment: Yes,you are right,it hijacks the cpu.I haven't noticed that.thanks.if a `Sleep()` in the `while`?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that another thread might change the value of that variable.  So it may not bother to look at it, because it "knows" that it can't change.  (*In practice* adding a Sleep() will work, but it both violates the language rules and is inefficient.)  If you want to wait for a thread to finish, wait on the thread object.  If you want to signal a thread to do something, use an event object.  If you need to use a variable from more than one thread, use a critical section to ensure that the threads take turns accessing it.

Comment: Thanks very much! The last additional question,why `it both violates the language rules and is inefficient`?inefficient may be wait time slice,but violates language rules?